# How to add a right click context menu to the tray icon

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a C# WPF application that has an icon in the system tray. I am currently using WPF NotifyIcon,The problem is that .NET 4.5 does not allow a WPF ContextMenu object to appear over the top of the Windows 7 taskbar.

Code which I written for tray icon is,

```
public partial class MonthView : MetroWindow
{

    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }

    public MonthView()
    {

            InitializeComponent();
            calMain.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today;
            Globals._globalController = new AppController();
            Globals._globalController.appTaskManager.setupLocal();
            Globals._globalController.setMonthViewWindow(this);

            Globals.ni = new NotifyIcon();
            Globals.ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"D:\MonthView.ico");
            Globals.ni.Visible = true;
            Globals.ni.Click +=
                delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
                {
                    this.Show();
                    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                };

    }

    protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Globals.ni.BalloonTipTitle = "MonthView";
            Globals.ni.BalloonTipText = "This is main window";
            Globals.ni.Visible = true;
            Globals.ni.ShowBalloonTip(500);
            base.OnStateChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK Taskbar is not the same as the tray icon. ContextMenu from a tray icon is pretty standard and Notifyicon has loads of examples demonstrating it. What is it your trying to get a ContextMenu from? the tray-icon or the Taskbar?

Comment: I just want, when I right click on my window icon, it should show me menubox with two or more menus.

Comment: [NotifyIcon - ContextMenu Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon#context_menus)